# Combine Bootstrap Tags Input and Jquery UI Selectable

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Im at the beginning of a hopefully long journey of trying to learn some programming skills.
This is my first question on stackoverflow :)

When I click on an item in my selectable list Id like it to be added to my Tags Input input field. (So I can either select from a predetermined list of selectable tags or input tags not on the list).

Im using backbone.js.
My html template file has this in it:

```
    <ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  </ol>
    <input type="text" class="form-control tags" name="tags" placeholder="tags" data-role="tagsinput">
```

But I dont know what to put in the js view file.  Right now all I have is the method pretty close to how I copied from Tags Input documentation. (im even unsure what should replace "some tag".

```
 events: {
  'addtags': 'addtags'
},

addtags: function(e) {
  $('input').tagsinput('add', 'some tag');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't take the items that have been selected out of the input if you click them a 2nd time, but it does let me click on an item in my selectable list Id like it to be added to my TagsInput input field, and I can still type any tag directly to the input field.

```
return BaseView.extend ({
    template: function() {
      $('.tags').tagsinput();
      $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {e.metaKey = true;}).selectable(); 
    },
    events: {
      'mousedown #selectable': 'addtags'
    },

    addtags: function(e) {
     // if($(e.target).hasClass('selected')){
       $('.tags').tagsinput('add', e.target.innerHTML);
    },
```